# New elements are not shown in the list after adding in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frontend

When the user clicks the `plus button`, I want the task array to appear as a list. I am not able to push my tasks to an array

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BsPlusLg } from "react-icons/bs";
import { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {

  const items = ["Pizza", "Burger", "Shawarma", "Biryani", "Butter Naan", "Panner", "Chapathi"];

  let tasks = [];

  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const changeValue = (event) => {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  }

  const searchedItems = tasks.filter((item) => {
    if(item.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())){
        return item;
      }
  })

  const handleClick = () => {
    if(items.length>0){
      tasks.push(items.pop());
    }
  }
```

On clicking the plus button, after the items are added to the tasks array, they should appear as a list.

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='navbar'>
        <input type="text" value={ searchValue } onChange={ changeValue } placeholder="Search"></input>
        {/* <div className="verticalLine"></div> */}
        <button onClick={ handleClick }><BsPlusLg /></button>
      </div>
      <hr/>
      <div className='list'>
        <ul>
          {(searchValue.length>0)&&(searchedItems.map((item) => {
            return <li key={item}>{item}</li>}))
          }
          {(searchValue.length===0)&&(tasks.map((item) => {
            return <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          }))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The `elements` in the tasks in the page are not being displayed when I `log` out of the tasks that are being pushed.

Comment: You need to call `setState` to trigger a state change. `tasks` isn't in state.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on your button does not update your component and will therefore rerender your list.

If if it would, it will run the whole function again and even call `let tasks = [];` again, which would reset your whole list. To update lists or whatever state you else need, you are required to use `useState` or similar hooks.

Because you also `pop` your `items` array, you might want to use two `useState` hooks and update them instead. Those will handle the internal state for you and isn't lost on a rerender. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html for more information. A solution might look like the following:

```
import "./styles.css";
import {useState} from 'react'


const BsPlusLg = () => <span >+</span>

const App = () => {

  const [items, setItems] = useState( ["Pizza", "Burger", "Shawarma", "Biryani", "Butter Naan", "Panner", "Chapathi"]);
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const changeValue = (event) => {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  }

  // searchedItems will be updated on each rerender
  const searchedItems = tasks.filter((item) => {
    if(item.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())){
        return item;
      }
  })

  const handleClick = () => {
    if(items.length === 0){
      // keep it simple and stop execution
      return;
    }
    
    // enforce a new reference
    let newItems = [...items];
   
    let item = newItems.pop();

    // enforce a new tasks reference
    let newTasks = [...tasks, item];
      
    setItems(newItems);
    setTasks(newTasks);


  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='navbar'>
        <input type="text" value={ searchValue } onChange={ changeValue } placeholder="Search"></input>
        {/* <div className="verticalLine"></div> */}
        <button onClick={ handleClick }><BsPlusLg /></button>
      </div>
      <hr/>
      <div className='list'>
        <ul>
          {(searchValue.length>0)&&(searchedItems.map((item) => {
            return <li key={item}>{item}</li>}))
          }
          {(searchValue.length===0)&&(tasks.map((item) => {
            return <li key={item}>{item}</li>
          }))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-albattani-jf1z6f?file=/src/App.js:0-1655

Answer (score 1):

It means that when React component be re-render, variables is not changed.
you must define 'item' variable as state.

```js
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
```

For push it:

```js
setTasks([...tasks, item.pop()])
```